# CSS: Padding stacking and colour only affecting text

Tags: html, css, colors, padding

I have looked for other ways to fix this including display:block; but none seem to work,
can any one tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<header>
<div id="menu">
    <div id="item"><b>HOME</b></div>
    <div id="login"><b>LOGIN</b></div>
<div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#login {
background-color: white;
color: black;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 30px;
height: 30px;
width: auto;
border: 3px solid white;
border-radius: 30px;
text-align: center;
float: right;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;}

#login :hover {
background-color: black;
color: white;}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ByFKG/)

The main problem I'm having is that for me in Chrome, the text background color changes but the padding does not, as I expected. I wish to find a way to do so.

Comment: Put this in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and give us the link.

Comment: Also, I'm aware I can do what I want with javascript, but i want to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Have you tried #login:hover (no space)?

Comment: The hover seems to work fine, both background and color. Your HTML is invalid, since you're not closing the outer div, but reopen a new one instead. But that's probably not the issue...

Comment: @Matthias Good find. Weird behavior too. In Chrome, the selector still seems to work, but it doesn't have rounded corners, even though that property is not defined in the block with the faulty selector. The colors, which *are* there, do work fine, despite the space.

Comment: @GolezTrol Oh wow, I didnt notice that.

Comment: @GolezTrol It's a quiet unclear to me what the OP is exactly looking for; But `#login :hover` represents the descendants on which the user hovers. In this case, the `<b>` element.

Comment: @GolezTrol That's weird, in chrome for me the border-radius works just fine, even with the broken div.

Comment: @GolezTrol Oh! So it should be #menu:hover ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space between the `#login :hover` so it will be `#login:hover` .

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure what the space was supposed to do, apparently they designate affecting children. I would upvote I was allowed to.

Comment: Why display add `inline-block` to `#login`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the background color of the div and not the text you should remove the space between `#login :hover` so that it is `#login:hover`

White-space matters for CSS selectors. If you put a space between it mean the next selector is for any descendant of the first selector.

When you have `#login :hover` it means that any hovered child/descendant element will be affected by the style rule but not `#login` itself.